# flot is it possible to set just the begining of the x axis?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I am working on flot jquery library, and I used to use this code in order to tell flot to inference the x-axis itself

```
xaxis: {

                   },
```

now i have a case in which I need to show the values starting from **zero** in x-axis, i don't care about last value, so I need flot to calculate it dinamically. it is possible to set just the begining ?

#### what I tried

I couldn't find such an option using google so I calculated the max value my self and I set the x-axis **manually** between zero and that max value. that approaches works in some cases, but i do need to handle all the senarios so i thought let me ask here first to see if there is a built-in option for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the minimum or maximum extent of the axes like this:

```
xaxis: {min: 0, max: 999}
```

See https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#customizing-the-axes

Comment: may you check my new question please?